# How to add quotes to conditions?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am struggling to get this line to run:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity-1 WHERE ISBN Number=" & Me.ISBN Number
```

I get syntax error when adding quotes to conditions. The table name is stock and it is in relation with the table books, by ISBN number and quantity. What needs to happen is that once this piece of code fires, it deducts 1 from the quantity in stock table where the ISBN number in both tables match.

EDIT 1:

I got it to work by adding a ISBN to the stock table and using the same one on a form to capture data using bar-code scanner, the issue however seems to be that if the ISBN number does not already exist in the stock table, it does not update, so I need to modify the query to first check if the ISBN has been captured before, and than update, otherwise create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `"'"` to parameter

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE stock SET quantity = quantity-1 WHERE ISBN Number=" &"'"& Me.ISBN Number&"'"
```

Comment: OK I got a solution, the code works fine but it's meant to decrease the value of stock by 1 when a book is issued, thus the solution is to have another form to capture stock, and one to decrease stock when it is issued out, using the above syntax fix that is.